# OwlError: No active component (a hook function should only be called in 'setup') in Odoo17

Tags: javascript, odoo

```
/** @odoo-module **/
import { Order } from "@point_of_sale/app/store/models";
import { patch } from "@web/core/utils/patch";
import { roundDecimals, roundPrecision } from "@web/core/utils/numbers";
import { useState } from "@odoo/owl";

patch(Order.prototype, {
    setup() {
        super.setup(...arguments);
        this.state = useState({
            points: 0,
        });
    },
    deductLoyaltyPoints() {
        let valsList = [];
        if (this.couponPointChanges) {
            console.log(this)
        }
        this.pos.lostPoints = valsList;
        return valsList;
    },
});
```

> point_of_sale.assets_prod.min.js:6087 OwlError: No active component (a
> hook function should only be called in 'setup')
> at getCurrent (point_of_sale.assets_prod.min.js:1010:67)
> at useState (point_of_sale.assets_prod.min.js:1014:80)
> at Order.setup (point_of_sale.assets_prod.min.js:11067:499)
> at new PosModel (point_of_sale.assets_prod.min.js:9220:48)
> at new Order (point_of_sale.assets_prod.min.js:9373:29)
> at Proxy.createReactiveOrder (point_of_sale.assets_prod.min.js:9611:31)
> at Proxy.load_orders (point_of_sale.assets_prod.min.js:9620:292)
> at async Proxy.after_load_server_data (point_of_sale.assets_prod.min.js:9572:67)
> at async Proxy.after_load_server_data (point_of_sale.assets_prod.min.js:11201:194)
> at async Proxy.load_server_data (point_of_sale.assets_prod.min.js:11058:364)